# pthread_cond_timedwait linking error with clock_gettime on Solaris 10

Tags: c++, time, solaris, pthreads

I have a bit of code which used `pthread_cond_wait` which looks like this:

```
struct timespec ts;
clock_getttime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timS);
ts.tv_sec += delay;

pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);
     pthread_cond_timedwait(&thread_cond, &a_mutex,&timS);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
```

But I get a linker error on compilation,

undefined symbol clock_gettime ... first referenced in (the file with that code)

This is the only linker error I get; if I comment out this block of code it compiles, so the pthread library is loading. I read somewhere that I need the -lc flag set, which I have done but it appears that I need to set something else too.

Does anybody know what?

This is on Solaris 10, using Sun's 5.8 compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -lc  answer is wrong.  You need to add -lrt   (presumably real time..?)

Answer (score 1):

On the command line try "man clock_getttime" or "man -k clock_getttime". This will give you the library to link to.
Then, include this line in your g++ -L/path/to/lib -lNameOfLib (or in the makefile as link flags)

Solaris Unix APIs are sometimes different than standard Unix functions.

Comment: Thanks, but I figured it out myself, by typing "clock_gettime solaris" into Google.
 I missed it the first time because I was too specific. The '-lrt' bit is mentioned in the Sun's man page under Synopsis. 
It doesn't say 'requires rt library' etc. 

But now I know :-)

Comment: Actually, POSIX 1003.1b mandates that `clock_gettime` is provided `-lrt`, so this should be the same regardless of which UNIX you're on, unless it's non-compliant.